# experiencing a layout issue with Livewire navigation in Laravel, where the page is opening at the same scroll position as the previous page

Tags: laravel, navigation, laravel-livewire, livewires, laravel-livewire-wireclick

I have a bug in livewire navigation when I use wire: navigation , when I click from home page to
Contact it works fine it open the page without loading the browser but getting a issue at loading is , suppose  if I am at footer of home page or down of home page and click to contact or any link it will open at the footer area where I was in 1st page , how to solve this

my front-navigation.blade.php

```
<div>
<header style="z-index: 999;">
            <nav id="navbar" style="z-index: 999;" class="fixed inset-x-0 z-20 w-full border-b border-gray-100 bg-white/80 backdrop-blur dark:border-gray-700/30 dark:bg-gray-900/80">
                <div class="mx-auto px-4 sm:px-12 xl:max-w-6xl xl:px-0">
                    <div class="relative flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between gap-6 lg:gap-0 lg:py-4">
                        <div class="relative z-20 flex w-full justify-between md:px-0 lg:w-max">
                            <a wire:navigate href="/" aria-label="logo" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                               <p style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;">GigaCode</p>
                            </a>

                            <button aria-label="humburger" id="hamburger" class="relative -mr-6 p-6 lg:hidden">
                                <div aria-hidden="true" class="m-auto h-0.5 w-5 rounded bg-sky-900 transition duration-300 dark:bg-gray-300"></div>
                                <div aria-hidden="true" class="m-auto mt-2 h-0.5 w-5 rounded bg-sky-900 transition duration-300 dark:bg-gray-300"></div>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="layer" aria-hidden="true" class="fixed inset-0 z-10 h-screen w-screen origin-bottom scale-y-0 bg-white/70 backdrop-blur-2xl transition duration-500 dark:bg-gray-900/70 lg:hidden"></div>
                        <div id="navlinks" class="invisible absolute top-full left-0 z-20 w-full origin-top-right translate-y-1 scale-90 flex-col flex-wrap justify-end gap-6 rounded-3xl border border-gray-100 bg-white p-8 opacity-0 shadow-2xl shadow-gray-600/10 transition-all duration-300 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:shadow-none lg:visible lg:relative lg:flex lg:w-auto lg:translate-y-0 lg:scale-100 lg:flex-row lg:items-center lg:gap-0 lg:border-none lg:bg-transparent lg:p-0 lg:opacity-100 lg:shadow-none lg:peer-checked:translate-y-0 dark:lg:bg-transparent">
                            <div class="text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-300 lg:pr-4">
                                <ul class="space-y-6 text-base font-medium tracking-wide lg:flex lg:space-y-0 lg:text-sm">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="./pages/solution.html" class="block transition hover:text-primary dark:hover:text-primaryLight md:px-4">
                                            <span>Work</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="./pages/customers.html" class="block transition hover:text-primary dark:hover:text-primaryLight md:px-4">
                                            <span>Services</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="./pages/pricing.html" class="block transition hover:text-primary dark:hover:text-primaryLight md:px-4">
                                            <span>Pricing</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="./pages/blog.html" class="block transition hover:text-primary dark:hover:text-primaryLight md:px-4">
                                            <span>News</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="./pages/about.html" class="block transition hover:text-primary dark:hover:text-primaryLight md:px-4">
                                            <span>Company</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mt-12 -ml-1 flex w-full flex-col space-y-2 border-primary/10 dark:border-gray-700 sm:flex-row md:w-max lg:mt-0 lg:mr-6 lg:space-y-0 lg:border-l lg:pl-6">
                                <a wire:navigate href="/register" class="relative ml-auto flex h-9 w-full items-center justify-center before:absolute before:inset-0 before:rounded-full before:bg-primary before:transition-transform before:duration-300 hover:before:scale-105 active:duration-75 active:before:scale-95 dark:before:border-gray-700 dark:before:bg-primaryLight sm:px-4 lg:before:border lg:before:border-gray-200 lg:before:bg-gray-100 lg:dark:before:bg-gray-800">
                                    <span class="relative text-sm font-semibold text-black dark:text-gray-900 lg:text-primary lg:dark:text-white">Get started</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
</div>
```

my app.blade.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/assets/favicon.2fc4673e.svg">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?        family=Urbanist:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,4          00&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.8.1/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Livewire Components -->
    @livewire('front-navigation')
    {{ $slot }}
    @livewire('front-footer')
    
    <!-- External JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.8.1/flowbite.min.js"></script>
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```